# Music partitions for piano

Tags: data-request, music, audio

I recently took up piano and I was surprised (read: shocked) not to find easily downloadable music partitions (sheets) on the internet. Now I am not looking for partitions that would be copyrighted, say, by Alicia Keys. I'm more hunting for public domain compositions by classical composers like Mozart, Bach or even Gershwin.

So is there a place on-line that allows to download public-domain partitions for classical (symphonic) music?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this website ([musopen.org](https://musopen.org/)) the other day and I bookmarked it. Looks interesting. From the about section of their website:

> We provide recordings, sheet music, and textbooks to the public for free, without copyright restrictions. Put simply, our mission is to set music free.

Comment: Looks very promising!

Comment: Indeed. I love initiatives like this one.

Answer (score 8):

You can find a very large classical music archive on http://imslp.org. It's the petrucci imslp (internet music score library project) music library with tons of free piano music scores.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [wide selection of sheet music that was created with the Musescore, the leading open-source music notation program](https://musescore.com/sheetmusic?instruments=0). You can filter by instrument and licence.

Please note that there is a [new project called OpenScore](https://fosdem.org/2017/schedule/event/openscore/), a collaboration of Musescore and IMSLP that aims at publishing all public domain music.